# System.Format.Exception Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, exception, accessor

I am having some trouble when calling a method from class A in class B.

Here is the method being called in class B

```
 public double monthlyExpense
        {
            get
            {
                return RealEstateApp.GetExpenses();
            }
```

The method itself from class A is

```
public static double GetExpenses()
{
    double insurance;
    double taxes;
    double utilities;
    string inValue;

    inValue = _insurance;
    insurance = double.Parse(inValue);
    inValue = _tax;
    taxes = double.Parse(inValue);
    inValue = _utilities;
    utilities = double.Parse(inValue);
    return (insurance / 12 + taxes / 12 + utilities);

}
```

I get the exception a the `insurance = double.Parse(inValue);` line.

The _insurance etc variables are being read from various text boxes:

```
RealEstateApp._insurance = txtBoxInsurance.Text;
RealEstateApp._tax = txtBoxTax.Text;
RealEstateApp._utilities = txtBoxUtilities.Text;
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Did you know what is in inValue?

Comment: What is the value in `inValue` ?

Comment: This should be solvable by simply [using the debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx), IMO.

Comment: Then it is the textbox. Check if you input it in the correct format.

Comment: @UweKeim I am a bit of noob to c# and programming in general so apologies if this is trivial.

Comment: Easy way , before the line that gives error, call Messagebox.Show(inValue); and see if the value in the message box is the value you are looking for.

Comment: I can't call MessageBox inside that method.

Comment: Okay upon further testing it looks like the data from the textboxes isn't being read and I am ending up with a 0 value using the TryParse method in the answer below. Any ideas why this may be?

Comment: You must validate your inputs. What is this application? Web? Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You might have inserted wrong input like space or any other character in `txtBoxInsurance`textbox firstly validate that textbox for double value then you will not get that exception.

Comment: That in fact is the case -  the data from the textboxes isn't being read and I am ending up with a 0 value using the TryParse method and an exception if using Parse.

Comment: Try this one. Convert.ToDouble(inVal);

Answer (score -1):

You can use TryParse instead of parse method

```
 inValue = _insurance;
double.TryParse(inValue,out insurance);//this will assign double value to insurance variable 
inValue = _tax;
double.TryParse(inValue,out taxes);
```

This will try to parse string value to double value and return true or false if it success or fail.

Comment: -1 This hides the problem. doesn't solves it.

Comment: Also this gives me a Cannot implicitly convert type bool to double error.

Comment: don't assign it to variable like this insurance =double.TryParse(inValue,out insurance );